# python averaging values in a row of a csv fie

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to produce a code that takes a .csv file that has the grades for students in this format:

`Ms. Student,100,100,90,70,100 
A Student,30,50,30,50,100 
Mr. Student,80,85,70,100,90`

and then takes the average of a certain student's grades. 
the user is supposed input the file name and the name of the student that they would like to find their grade average for.

I have seen many posts that find average values for certain columns but none that do this for rows, please help.

Comment: please do give code of what you've tried so far

Comment: The reason there aren't many posts that find averages for rows is that it's much easier than doing it for columns. You get one row at a time (whether you're using `csv.reader`, as you should be, or trying to parse lines manually), so you just convert the values in `row[1:]` to numbers and average them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import csv

def FindAverage(student_name,file_name):
    with open(file_name,newline='') as csvfile: #open your csv file
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==student_name: #if the student is found
                grades=[int(i) for i in row[1:]] #slice the row to get grades and convert to int
                print("Average : ",sum(grades)/len(grades)) #print average


FindAverage("Mr. Student","grades.csv")
OUTPUT : Average :  85.0
```